# Application Openlayers with React

Tags: openlayers, vercel

I'm doing an application using Openlayers, react, next.js. When deploy to vercel I have a problem when instantiation of OLVectorLayer.

The log of the deployment not says information about the problem but if I delete the instantiation of `OLVectorLayer`, everything works fine.

I use it like this:

```
import OLVectorLayer from "ol/layer/Vector";
import { Vector as VectorSource } from 'ol/source';
const test = new VectorSource({
    features: []
});

let vectorLayer = new OLVectorLayer({
    source: test
});
```

Am I missing something?

WEB- https://viewer-map-nine.vercel.app/

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your page, including a regexp with invalid characters. The main React error comes from Next.js and says that the server-generated page does not match the one rendered by the client. Most probably this has nothing to do with Openlayers and this code that you are showing has other side effects that provoke that error.

And by the way, I suggest you try rlayers (https://github.com/mmomtchev/rlayers) which supports Openlayers on Next.js out of the box. I am its author.

Comment: Hi mmomtchev, thanks for your answer and suggestion but I preffer do it with no extra library. Besides, my code in localhost works but when its deployed it appears like errors with deploying. I'll continue investing a little bit more, thanks